# How can I cancel the unpleasant indentation of the enumerate environment?

Tags: lists, enumerate, indentation, enumitem

I want to change the default indentation of the enumerate environment, so I use the enumitem package. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[default-range=1]{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemindent=2em,listparindent=2em}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=2em}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum
        \item \begin{enumerate}
            \item \lipsum

                \lipsum
            \item \lipsum
            \item \lipsum
        \end{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But then I get some unpleasant indentation between the 2nd \item of the first level(2.) and the 1st \item of the second level(a).

[image]

Is there anything I can do to cancel this indentation without changing the others?

Comment: Similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358251/custom-enumitem-list-with-a-unique-first-line

Comment: Even more similar: [enumerate - Escape nested list indentation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458504/escape-nested-list-indentation?rq=1)